# Удаленная перезагрузка компьютера

Tags: администрирование, железо

Обслуживаемый компьютер на Windows XP SP3 находится в 5 километрах от нас, бывает зависания, что только вручную надо клацнуть, шкаф закрыт и сменный персонал не может добраться,ключ никто не оставит. НУ берем машины и едем, так себе идея,можно схлопотать простой, а можно как то удаленно решить этот вопрос,если машина зависла?
Бывает пинги идут, а подключится удаленно aspia,vnc не получается, она как бы перегружается и так пока вручную не клацнешь.
Как можно решить эту проблему?

Comment: Приехать, подключить монтор/клавиатуру и разобраться почему так происходит. В противном случае поставить что-то управляемое в разрыв эл. цепи, например, управляемую розетку.

Comment: Конечно разбираемся, если было бы что-то постоянное, перейти на windows 7 пытаемся, как изучим исходники.

Comment: 1) Выявить из-за чего зависает - устранить. 2) Можно прогой проверять какой-то параметр системы и ребутать (например если загрузка ОЗУ > 90%) 3) Ребутать автоматом по регламенту, скажем каждый день...или неделю (если +/- есть фиксированный интервал межно включением/зависанием)

Comment: Ой,пусть лучше виснит,чем скажут что мой  reboot остановил производство.
Вот идея с управляемой резеткой мне нравится с  разрывом цепи, может найду что-то с ethernet.

Comment: Cleware ищите или APC -- полно предложений на рынке, а вообще разберитесь с истинной причиной.

Comment: Наидешёвейший вариант — Orange Pi за $5 рядом с виснущим компом, как тут, только на reset: https://qna.habr.com/q/237167. Наидешевейший — значит, "не самый надёжный", они и сами виснут :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

То, что ты ищешь - называется `WatchDog`. Концептуально выглядит так:

- Железка цепляется к компу через какой-либо порт USB\COM\LPT\Astral.
- Провод от неё кидается на колодку материнки в штырьки `SW_Reset`.
- На ОС ставится драйвер\прога, которая опрашивает эту самую железку и сбрасывает внутренний таймер (в самой железке).
- Если комп завис, то прога соответственно не сбрасыват таймер вачдога и он посылает на провода `reset`.
- Комп уходит в хард резет. Все счастливы и довольны.

В серверных материнках обычно такое уже есть прям с завода.

Я помогал реализовывать такую штуку у друга на даче. Брали "usb-флэшку" у [этих](https://open-dev.ru/shop) ребят. На винде прога занимает метров 10, на линуксе вообще ничего не надо - там просто пишется скрипт на 5 строк, который через `echo` пушит в `/dev/ttyACM0`.

Answer (score 2):

Была такая байка времен 90-х годов. У кого-то тоже часто зависал компьютер под виндой и нужно было удаленно нажимать сброс. Так вот, ребята поставили рядом компьютер с линуксом и при зависании винды удаленно подавали на компьютер с линуксом команду "выдвинуть-убрать CD привод". А компьютер с линуксом поставили так, чтобы крышка CD привода нажимала кнопку "СБРОС" на компьютере с виндой. :-)